# Symbolic Multivariate Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic

If I try to input a symbolic multivariate distribution, I do not get a useful result.

```
PDF[MultinormalDistribution[m, S], x]

(* During evaluation of MultinormalDistribution::vrprm: The value m at position 1 in MultinormalDistribution[m,S] is expected to be a list of real numbers. *)

(* During evaluation of MultinormalDistribution::vrprm: The value m at position 1 in MultinormalDistribution[m,S] is expected to be a list of real numbers.*)
(* PDF[MultinormalDistribution[m, S], x] *)
```

Clearly, Mathematica could return an appropriate symbolic expression.  Is there any way of making it do so?

Answer (score 8):

You need to supply Mathematica with the structure of your variables:

```
(* dimension of distribution *)
n = 2;

PDF[
 MultinormalDistribution[
  Array[Subscript[m, ##] &, n],
  Array[Subscript[S, Sequence @@ Sort@{##}] &, {n, n}]
  ],
 Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, n]
 ]
```

[image]
We use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) to construct variables of the form `Subscript[var,i,j,…]` (you can of course use any other form that is more convenient). Note that `S` is explicitly made symmetric by sorting the indices. The code works without this, but this way there are no "fake" parameters.

*Note:* As pointed out by @BobHanlon in the comments, `Subscript` can often cause issues if used blindly. For actual use, it is much safer to simply use indexed variables such as `Array[x, n]`.

Comment: Rather than using subscripted variables, I recommend using indexed variables and then using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display the indexed variables as subscripted variables. Subscripted variables tend to cause problems in solvers.

Comment: I am aware of that - I just thought that for a quick demonstration, it would be good enough and it's easy to read. But I will add a comment to the answer to point out potential issues.

Comment: A very useful answer, but I was hoping for an expression  that worked in terms of vector and matrix inputs (of unspecified dimension).

Comment: @BobHanlon is there an answer you can link to that would detail an appropriate use of the Format method you reference?

Comment: @CATrevillian - For a simple example, consider

`Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n];

x /@ {m, n, 1, 2, 3}`

Also see [`documentation details section`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) and  [`link`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171964/9362)